# Oracle SQL Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am creating a report for a client to retrieve invoices and their ship to location. Currently the query is very slow and I would be grateful if anyone can advise how to optimize the query. I do have lot of outer joins in the query and I believe this might be the issue.

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
SELECT 
b.operating_unit, 
b.trading_partner, 
b.invoice_date, 
b.type,
b.gl_date, 
b.invoice_num, 
b.invoice_id, 
b.quantity,
b.unit_price,
b.uom,
b.invoice_currency_code, 
b.payment_method_code, 
b.terms,
b.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
b.LINE_NUMBER,
b.item_code,
b.VAT_CODE,
b.amount,
b.invoice_amount, 
b.vat_amount,
b.discount_amount,
b.price_variance,
b.total_amount,
b.status,
b.ship_to_location
FROM(
SELECT 
a.operating_unit, 
a.trading_partner, 
a.invoice_date, 
a.type,
a.gl_date, 
a.invoice_num, 
a.invoice_id, 
a.quantity,
ROUND(a.unit_price,2) unit_price,
a.uom,
a.invoice_currency_code, 
a.payment_method_code, 
a.terms,
a.LINE_NUMBER,
a.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
a.item_code,
a.VAT_CODE,
--CASE WHEN a.status = 'CANCELLED' THEN NULL
--ELSE a.VAT_CODE END AS VAT_CODE,
sum(a.AMOUNT) amount,
a.invoice_amount, 
sum(a.vat_amount) vat_amount,
sum(a.discount_amount) discount_amount,
sum(a.price_variance) price_variance,
sum(a.total_amount) total_amount,
CASE WHEN a.status = 'FULLY' THEN 'Fully Applied'
WHEN a.status = 'UNAPPROVED' THEN 'Unvalidated'
WHEN a.status = 'NEEDS REAPPROVAL' THEN 'Needs Revalidation'
WHEN a.status = 'APPROVED' THEN 'Validated'
WHEN a.status = 'NEVER APPROVED' THEN 'Never Validated'
WHEN a.status = 'CANCELLED' THEN 'Cancelled'
WHEN a.status = 'UNPAID' THEN 'Unpaid'
WHEN a.status = 'AVAILABLE' THEN 'Available'
END AS status,
a.ship_to_location
from(
Select 
    hz.name operating_unit,
    aia.INVOICE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE type,     
    aps.vendor_name trading_partner,    
    aia.INVOICE_DATE,    
    aia.gl_date, 
    aia.invoice_num, 
    aia.INVOICE_AMOUNT,          
    aida.invoice_id,
    APIDA.LINE_NUMBER,
    APIDA.QUANTITY_INVOICED QUANTITY,
    APIDA.UNIT_PRICE,
    APIDA.UOM,
    aia.INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE,
    aia.PAYMENT_METHOD_CODE,    
    apt.name terms,
    APIDA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
    APIDA.ITEM_CODE,
    case when apida.line_type_lookup_code <> 'IPV' THEN APIDA.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS AMOUNT,  
    --case when aida.line_type_lookup_code = 'REC_TAX' THEN aida.RECOVERY_RATE_NAME END AS VAT_CODE, 
    APIDA.VAT_CODE,
    APIDA.VAT_AMOUNT,
    0 DISCOUNT_AMOUNT,
    case when apida.line_type_lookup_code = 'IPV' THEN APIDA.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END AS PRICE_VARIANCE,      
    APIDA.TOTAL_AMOUNT, 
    APPS.AP_INVOICES_PKG.GET_APPROVAL_STATUS
            (
             aia.INVOICE_ID
            ,aia.INVOICE_AMOUNT
            ,aia.PAYMENT_STATUS_FLAG
            ,aia.INVOICE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE
            ) status,
    APIDA.SHIP_TO_LOCATION  
    --b.description ship_to_location
from (SELECT AILA.INVOICE_ID, AILA.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE, AILA.LINE_NUMBER, aila.TAX_CLASSIFICATION_CODE VAT_CODE, AILA.QUANTITY_INVOICED, AILA.UNIT_PRICE, AILA.UNIT_MEAS_LOOKUP_CODE UOM, X.invoice_distribution_id, X.Description ITEM_DESCRIPTION, msi.segment1 item_code, NVL(X.AMOUNT, 0) AMOUNT, NVL(B.TAX_AMOUNT,0) VAT_AMOUNT, (NVL(X.AMOUNT, 0) +  NVL(B.TAX_AMOUNT,0)) TOTAL_AMOUNT,HR.DESCRIPTION SHIP_TO_LOCATION 
FROM ap_invoice_lines_all aila, ap_invoice_distributions_all X, MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS msi, hr_locations hr,
 (SELECT A.INVOICE_ID, A.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE, A.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER,  A.CHARGE_APPLICABLE_TO_DIST_ID, SUM(A.AMOUNT) TAX_AMOUNT
        FROM ap_invoice_distributions_all A
        WHERE 1=1
        AND A.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE  = 'REC_TAX'
        GROUP BY A.INVOICE_ID, A.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE, A.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER,  A.CHARGE_APPLICABLE_TO_DIST_ID) B 
WHERE AILA.INVOICE_ID = X.INVOICE_ID(+)
AND X.INVOICE_ID =  B.INVOICE_ID(+)
AND X.invoice_distribution_id = B.CHARGE_APPLICABLE_TO_DIST_ID(+)
and msi.inventory_item_id(+) = aila.inventory_item_id 
AND AILA.SHIP_TO_LOCATION_ID = HR.SHIP_TO_LOCATION_ID
and aila.line_number = X.INVOICE_LINE_NUMBER(+)
AND AILA.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE  != 'REC_TAX' AND AILA.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE  != 'NONREC_TAX' 
--AND AILA.INVOICE_ID = '10T52233547'
)APIDA,
ap_invoice_distributions_all aida, ap_invoices_all aia, ap_suppliers aps, ap_terms apt, hr_organization_units hz
where aia.invoice_id = aida.invoice_id(+)
and aia.invoice_id = APIDA.invoice_id(+)
and aps.vendor_id = aia.vendor_id
and apt.term_id = aia.terms_id
and hz.ORGANIZATION_ID = aia.org_id
--and aia.invoice_NUM = '123456'
--and aida.LINE_TYPE_LOOKUP_CODE = 'REC_TAX'
/* Parameters */
and hz.ORGANIZATION_ID between NVL(:p_operating_unit_from, hz.ORGANIZATION_ID) and NVL(:p_operating_unit_to, hz.ORGANIZATION_ID)
and aia.INVOICE_DATE between NVL(:p_invoice_date_from, aia.INVOICE_DATE) and NVL(:p_invoice_date_to, aia.INVOICE_DATE)
and aps.vendor_id between NVL(:p_trading_partner_from, aps.vendor_id) and NVL(:p_trading_partner_to, aps.vendor_id)
and aia.gl_date between NVL(:p_gl_date_from, aia.gl_date) and NVL(:p_gl_date_to, aia.gl_date)
order by hz.name, aps.vendor_name, APIDA.SHIP_TO_LOCATION, APIDA.ITEM_DESCRIPTION)a
group by a.operating_unit, 
a.trading_partner, 
a.invoice_date, 
a.gl_date, 
a.invoice_num, 
a.invoice_amount, 
a.invoice_id, 
a.invoice_currency_code, 
a.payment_method_code, 
a.terms,
a.ITEM_DESCRIPTION,
a.item_code, 
a.VAT_CODE, 
a.quantity,
a.unit_price,
a.LINE_NUMBER,
a.uom,
a.status,
a.type,
a.ship_to_location)b
order by b.operating_unit, b.trading_partner, b.ship_to_location, b.invoice_date, b.gl_date, b.invoice_num, b.LINE_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ORDER BY` in a subquery, which has no effect, so you should remove it. If the optimizer doesn't already notice and ignore it, this would speed up the query.

The comma-separated join syntax you are using was standard in the 1980s, but is considered error-prone and hard to read now. You may want to replace it with explicite joins (e.g. `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`) for readability and maintainability. However, I see no errors in your joins, so you would gain nothing else than that.

The outmost query is superfluous, but shouldn't cause any slowdown. So no problem either.

This is simply a rather complicated query with some outer joins and two group by clauses. No obvious error. Check if you have indexes on the columns used in your where clauses. You may want some composite Indexes, too. I expect all IDs to be indexed already. I suggest the following three additional indexes:

- ap_invoice_lines_all(invoice_id, line_number)
- ap_invoice_distributions_all(invoice_id, invoice_line_number)
- ap_invoice_distributions_all(line_type_lookup_code)

Comment: Thanks for the advice Sir. Appreciate your effort to reply to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I am a newbie to Oracle SQL. I did my investigation and the issue is not with the outer joins but rather with the distinct. It has to group and sort a large amount of data and this is causing the delay.

I have to rework this code and avoid using DISTINCT. When I have a solution, I will post here for other newbies like me can learn something new.

Comment: There is no `DISTINCT` in the query given.